# Email sender showing "Relay denied" error

Tags: vb.net, email, smtp

I am using this code in my email sender but getting an error.
First I tried with gmail, where it was sent correctly, but when i try with smtp2go I get a "Relay denied for unauthenticated sender" error.

I also want to add a "From Email" option and "Sender Name" and "Receiver Name".
Can anyone help me?
I'm using Visual Basic 10.

Here is the email sender code

```vb
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Mail
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub FlatButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FlatButton1.Click
        Try
            Dim client As New SmtpClient
            Dim message As New MailMessage
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = False
            client.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(Me.TextBox1.Text, Me.TextBox2.Text)
            client.Port = "2525"
            client.EnableSsl = True
            client.Host = "mail.smtp2go.com"
            message = New MailMessage
            message.From = New MailAddress(Me.TextBox3.Text)
            message.To.Add(Me.TextBox4.Text)
            message.Subject = Me.TextBox5.Text
            message.IsBodyHtml = True
            message.Body = Me.TextBox6.Text
            client.Send(message)
            MsgBox("Mail Sent", MsgBoxStyle.ApplicationModal, Nothing)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.ApplicationModal, Nothing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Me.FlatComboBox1.Text = "mail.smtp2go.com"
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox3_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox3.TextChanged
    End Sub

    Private Sub FlatComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FlatComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: They key word that jumped out at me from the error was "`unauthenticated`". Beyond that, though, I really don't know.